# Access my IOTA balance to send and receive

Tags: confirmation, balances

I see my iota balance but I have a few pending bundles in the History section (two confirmed out of 7).

Question: If I see my balance, does that mean everything is ok and I can move the balance out safely? or do I need to have all items confirmed in the history? if so how do I do that. I have reattached and promoted them many times.

Comment: You don't need all items confirmed in the history. Besides, if your unconfirmed transactions are pretty old (days old) then probably they have become orphaned transactions, which will never be confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why there might be pending transactions shown in the wallet

- You reattached a transaction and the reattachment confirmed, making the original transaction pending forever (this does not apply to promotions. Promoted transactions will also confirm the original transaction)
- You sent some IOTA (or somebody sent it to you) but the transaction did not confirm and nobody wanted to reattach it.

In the first case, you will see an indentical transaction (with same bundle hash) that is confirmed (also, tangle explorers like thetangle.org will show your original transaction as "reattachment confirmed"). You don't have to do anything with these transactions.

In the second case, there are still pending transactions. In case you are trying to transfer your IOTA now, it could result in a double-spend or in some IOTA remaining (if an incoming transaction gets confirmed later). These transactions will not have a second confirmed transaction with the same bundle hash, and they will show up as "pending" on thetangle.org. You should try to promote/reattach these transactions to get them confirmed before spending your IOTA.

In any case, if you are using a recent version of the official desktop wallet (**not** the Android one), it will warn you when you try to perform a transaction that may result in a double-spend. So you can try in any case, and just stop if you get a warning.